# XSL select value of xml attribute as integer

Tags: xml, xslt, select, attributes, value-of

i am trying to select some xml attributes from decimal values to integers.
For example

```
<ItemIn quantity="1.0">
```

The value of @quantity must be selected as integer i.e. only 1.

I am using

```
<xsl:value-of select="@quantity">
```

Is there a way to select quantity as integer i.e. as 1 ?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear and the example is ambiguous. What do you want the result be when the given quantity is 1.6?  Note that `xsl:value-of` **always** outputs a *text node* - not an *integer* or any other data type.

Comment: It is quantity of items.. it cannot be decimal value. You cannot buy 1.6 quantity of PC for example. That is why I want to remove the decimal part from it and select it as integer :)

Comment: "*I want to remove the decimal part from it and select it as integer*" Those are two separate things. They just happen to coincide in your example.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right about this. Thank you for the comment, i wll have it in mind for my future questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`XSLT format-number() Function`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_formatnumber.asp) with a single `#` as format like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(@quantity, '#')" />
```

Comment: I suspect a simple `<xsl:value-of select="number(@quantity)" />` would be sufficient - at least in the given example.

Comment: Also work, ty. You could ad it as comment if you want.